# How to send messages via svSocket between R session and rstudio-server on headless Ubuntu?

Tags: rstudio-server, svsocket

I have a headless R server which serves the recent `rstudio-server`.

I need to pass it some objects via [`svSocket`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svSocket/index.html).

Because the `svSocket` uses TCL/TK message queue, which needs a working X11 session I know I need to embed things in a virtual X11 environment.

I log into the server via ssh and in the command line I put the following commands:

```
sudo Xvfb :0 &
export DISPLAY=":0"
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver &
R
```

Then I log into the rstudio-server via its web interface and type these commands:

```
> library(svSocket)
> startSocketServer()
[1] TRUE
```

then, on this R session I put the following

```
> library(svSocket)
> con<-socketConnection(host='localhost', port=8888)
> evalServer(con,'2+2')
```

I expect to get "`4`" result, but instead the R hangs, never returning any prompt.

If I replace the rstudio-server with the regular R, everything works correctly.

What is so special in the way it treats `rsession` that this example breaks? How to fix it?

`SessionInfo()`:

> ```
> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
>
> locale:
>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
>  [3] LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
>  [5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
>  [7] LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the port number when you start the socket connection

```
> library(svSocket)
> startSocketServer(port=8888)
```

It should work after this.